# Problem accessing HashMap data from another class

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Am having a problem accessing the data in a HashMap. It was created in one class and is being called from another. See below;

*Created*

```
public class LoadDatabase {
    public Map virusDatabase = new HashMap();
    ...
    public void toHash(String v_Name, String signature) {
        virusDatabase.put(v_Name, signature);
    }
    ...
    public void printDatabase() {   // This method is displaying correct data, so is being stored.
        Iterator iterator = virusDatabase.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(key + " = " + virusDatabase.get(key));
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

*Need Access*

```
public class LCS {
    LoadDatabase lb = new LoadDatabase();
    Tokenizer T = new Tokenizer();
    ...
    public void buildDataLCS(String[] inTokens) {
        Iterator iterator = lb.virusDatabase.keySet().iterator();
        ...                
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            String key = (String) iterator.next();
            String v_sig = (String) lb.virusDatabase.get(key);
            System.out.println(v_sig);  //Example of problem, nothing printed
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Why is the problem happening? Could you point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of the 2 issues,

1. You are not putting anything there. As I can't see your invocation of `toHash(String v_Name, String signature)` method.
2. You are using 2 different instances of `LoadDatabase` class, somehow. Try making `LoadDatabase` singleton.

Comment: @Carlos: Glad it sorted thing out.

Answer (score 1):

Carlos

I suspect you are not putting what you think you are putting into the map, or the keys when you put data in are not the same as when you take values out.  I would log/print the key/val you put in, and then log/print the key/val you try to get out.

Comment: in the class `loadDatabase` I have a method `printHash` and the values are there 100% as desired. That is what is confusing me. I will add the method for other people to know as u make a fair point

Comment: also print the keys in buildDataLCS.  Also, Strings can have whitespace on the ends which could be messing you up.

Comment: actually i just tried printing the key -out- and also it's empty. Is like am accessing another (empty) map